# Looking for a highchart with dropdown option

Tags: highcharts

I am looking for a highchart that looks like the following:
[Select category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOvo7.png)
I have a highchart license to highchart library of visualizations. Any suggestions?
Thanks
Shuree

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML select element to control chart, at this example I change data.

```
var select = document.getElementById('select');
```

The chart is updated by this method --> [Highcharts.Series#update](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update)

```
select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  chart.series[0].update({
    data: data[this.value]
  });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m84f3spx/4/